# How can we pass parameters to constructors in a Fragment while using them in Espresso Test Cases

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I am trying to launch a fragment with object as a parameter in my Espresso test case and I am unable to do so.

val homeFragment= launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)

But I want to send an object to the HomeFragment class.

For eg:
val homeType:HomeType

I want to pass the homeType object to the below line of code, need help with how to do it.
val homeFragment= launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)

I have looked into documentation and stackoverflow link(added below) and I am not able to get the desired solution.

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/test

[Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the launchFragmentInContainer function documentation, you can see that have parameter fragmentArgs of type Bundle. You can use it to pass arguments to fragment. I don't know how exactly your class HomeType looks like but remember that within Bundle you can pass only custom classes that implements java.io.Serializable or Parcelable.
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/testing/package-summary#launchFragmentInContainer(android.os.Bundle,kotlin.Int,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State,androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory)

Comment: Thank you for the response.
HomeType is a class with couple of variables.

I want to pass the object of HomeType class to HomeFragmentClass like given below:

val homeFragment= launchFragmentInContainer<HomeFragmentClass>(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)

I wanted to pass it as an object via constructor of HomeFragmentClass.

So I have to pass my object as a bundle?

Comment: Yes, you have to create Bundle and add an instance of your class to it. It will look something like this:
`val bundle = bundleOf("custom_key" to homeType)`
bundleOf function comes from android ktx